# odoo 9 how to inherit many2one field value from parent view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I have hospital appointment registration model that is relates to lab test model :

```
'lab_test_ids': fields.one2many('oeh.medical.lab.test','apoointment','Lab Tests', readonly=False,states={'Completed': [('readonly', True)]}),
```

in the view I have a TAB (page) under appointment form :

```
page string="Lab Tests"> <field name="lab_test_ids" context="{'default_appointment': active_id}" domain="[('appointment', '=', active_id)">
```

My challenge is that I have patient and physician in both views (selection fields) that relate to two other models. I was wondering if I could SET value for a patient field in the parent view and inherit that value to the child view (Lab test). how can I do that?

NOW i use domain to filter through the patient. and the candidate patient is Only one . how can I set this value to the field automatically.

```
> <field name="patient" domain="[('id', '=', parent.patient)]"
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% fully understand the question but you only have a few options to handle the scenario of copying field data between views.

1.
**Onchange Field**. Create an onchange if they are on the same view. (Don't believe this will work for you.)

```py
lab_test = fields.One2many(...)

@api.onchange('lab_test')
def _onchange_set_lab_test(self):
    self.other_field = self.lab_test
```

2.
**Related Field**. Setup the child as a related field if it's of the same type:

```py
child = fields.One2many(related='lab_test')
```

3.
**Computed Field**. Setup the child as a computed field with pulls whatever information you need.

```py
child = fields.One2many(compute='_compute_child_field')
```